# Best way for theme folders structure in Code Igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, themes

I want to make my web app theme-able. There are 3 ways I researched:

### Solution 1:

```
- application
    - views
        - theme1
            - template files
        - theme2
            - template files
        - admin template
- css
    - theme1
    - theme2
- js
    - theme1
    - theme2
- images
    - theme1
    - theme2
```

It is working well. However it is not comfortable when placing files in separated folders.

### Solution 2

```
- application
    - views
        - theme1
            - css
            - js
            - images
            - template files
        - theme2
            - css
            - js
            - images
            - template files
        - admin template
```

And I changed /application/.htaccess to

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It is also working well, but is it good for security? (i'm not good at .htaccess)

## Solution 3

```
- application
    - views
        - admin template
- themes
    - theme1
        - css
        - js
        - images
        - template files
    - theme2
        - css
        - js
        - images
        - template files
```

And I changed views path to theme folder in MY_Loader.

It looks like better structure. I have an issue with admin template.
Becuse I want also to place admin template files in folder views as a core system,
I don't know how to make views load function can see files in both of place.

Could everyone please advice me for the best solutions.
Thanks and Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MY_Loader, I assume you're extended the view() function to look for the right view in a different location? If that's the case, why not create a new function in MY_Loader called adminView() or something which is just a copy of the view() function, but it looks for views in the admin location.

In your controller for methods that are calling theme specific files, you would call:

```
$this->load->view('template');
```

and when you need to call an admin template, you would call:

```
$this->load->adminView('template);
```

Comment: Hi cchana,

Thank you for your response. That will be good way for me to learn.

Beside that, I used HMVC for CI. I can also place admin template in modules folder now.

Regards,

Comment: Glad it was of use and if that's the route you're taking, you can accept the answer to close the question off :)

Comment: Just a question, is the .htaccess in solution 2 good? Because it will change permission of application folder. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: Have you tried that .htaccess file out? Not 100% sure what it would do. When you say it will change the permission, how so? I can't really tell what it does. The fix I posted for solution 3 would mean that the .htaccess file is only used to remove index.php from the URL, not to handle application logic.

Comment: Original .htaccess file is placed in application folder with "Deny from all". Then, I can't browse to css, js or images folders in views/theme. So, I tried to chang .htaccess as same as solution 2 (following another guide) to able to browse to css... I just thought that way is not safe because it changed application logic (someone can access other folders). I'm not sure because I am not good at .htaccess and security. Anyway, I have used another way, and I am glad with it. Thank you. I will close this question. :D